# Device Registry Management API - Devices - Case-insensitive search

Tags: eclipse-hono

How to make case-insensitive search when searching devices for a tenant with optional filters, paging and sorting options by using Device Registry Management API?

Answer (score 1):

Currently *case-insensitive* search of devices/tenants is not supported. I think it is nice to have this feature. I would suggest to create a issue (feature request) in Hono github repository (https://github.com/eclipse/hono/issues).

*Note:* Hono's [MongoDB](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/user-guide/mongodb-based-device-registry/) based device registry implementation supports search using optional filters. The search feature is not yet implemented in the [JDBC](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/user-guide/jdbc-based-device-registry/) based registry.